# Nuget push with -SkipDuplicate on ProGet feed

Tags: nuget, proget

When publishing packages with the same version to ProGet free v5.1.22 using the CLI comand `nuget push` with the parameter `-SkipDuplicate` I get exit code 1 and the result code is 403 (Package Already Exists).
I'm using nuget v5.4.0.
I tried publishing to nuget.org and it works as expected, i.e., I get a message stating the package already exists, but the exit code is 0, which allows my CI build to proceed.
Why is SkipDuplicate not working as expected in ProGet?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is because the nuget only ignores 409 (Conflict) return code when this options is set, regarding the dotnet core documentation (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-push)

This information is not available on nuget.exe CLI doc page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-push).

I am about to raise a ticket to Inedo about this compatibility issue.